# When was a file used by another program

Tags: macos, performance, terminal, stata

I have a file with a series of 750 csv files. I wrote a Stata that runs through each of these files and performs a single task. The files are quite big, and my program has been running for more than 12 hours.

Is there is a way to know which was the last of the csv files that was used by Stata? I would like to know if the code is somewhere near finishing. I thought that organizing the 750 files by "last used" would do the trick, but it does not.

Next time I should be more careful about signalling how the process is going... 
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the work? The most basic approaches are probably using `display` and creating a log.

Comment: `display` of filename (and possibly number of files  so far) is a basic approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OS X terminal, cd to the directory containing the CSV files, and run the command

```
ls -lUt | head
```

which should show your files, sorted by the most recent access time, limited to the 10 most recently accessed.

Answer (score 0):

On the most basic level you can use `display` and `log` your session:

```
clear
set more off

local myfiles file1 file2 file3

forvalues i = 1/3 {
    display "processing file`i'"
    // <do-something-with-file>
}
```

See also `help log`.

Comment: Yes, this would have been the ideal. My question was more about knowing how the process was doing, given that I had forgotten to display that line `display "processing file`i'"`.... Thank you

Comment: Do you mean how to inspect _while the code is running_?

Comment: If so, I guess there may be some indirect way if your processing code produces something that is auditable (e.g. another file), but I'm guessing it doesn't. If not, I can't say how.